# How to track size of downloaded content in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement to track the size of content that user downloads from our web application (based on spring boot 2.x). Even when download wasn't successful I should write down (to database) how many data was transferred.
So far I've found [CountingOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) which probably should do the trick but I'm also looking for other solutions.

Does anybody used `CountingOutputStream` and have some gotchas how to handle the downloads properly or did somebody implemented this with another solution?

Comment: Some requirements are still unclear:
What data needs to be counted? Send data? Transferred and received data? Compressed uncompressed (not only file but HTTP compression)? Count file traffic vs HTTP traffic. What about network retransmit? Also what is a user? A session? A named user? A customer? All traffic for billing? Depending on those questions your solution might do the trick or you need to look into other options on other levels (e.g. JMX monitoring). Also if the data is huge (which I suspect) normally the system you read data from comes with tooling as well (e.g. S3).

Comment: Thanks for questions. Well we are trying to measure the download of data (big zip files) that is stored in azure blobstorage. Blobstorage doesn’t provide such metrics on blob level so we want to create some “proxy” where we will compute this. User is oauth (keycloak) entity which should be always authorised for such download.

Comment: So you're building an API around an API with which additional value? What are you loosing at the same time? Having worked with S3 I cannot believe Azure cannot provide a way for that use case. It's been build for that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into Azure documentation it's capable of storing fine grained logs for complete file access incl. size and access count. Details can be found here in the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal

[image]

Now the question is how do your customers access the date. Easiest way would be an Azure user, because that will allow file access right management and automatic split of the metrics.

A different approach can be taken if the files are customer specific and always dedicated to a single customer. So if all files are in a customer specific pattern you can filter open that one (e.g. customer ID in filename/filepath).

Azure Blob storage log can be analysed by parameters as well. e.g.:

[image]

Available oarameter list is quite large:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage-reference#metrics-dimensions

If data is same you need to find a matching parameter that ensures the split of data consumption by customer. You might even be able to filter it directly if you analyse the referrer and your proxy includes the customer_Id as a parameter.

To sum it up my preference would be:

1. use the Azure user management to add a user per customer with all the additional benefits you gain
2. If you have a filename pattern and dedicated, non-overlapping files use the file path to filter
3. If not use a parameter from your proxy API.

In all cases an analysis of the Azure logs will do the trick. Benefit is you're using the system that also creates the bill, so you should be consistent on the number the business side sees. Error cases will also be handled by Azure: What happens if someone hits your system pretty hard and the DB log fails? What will be billed on half downloaded files? What will be billed on retransmits because of routing issues etc. The Azure logs might not be perfect in all of those cases, but if something slips Azure it will not be billed to you as well - so you're consistent and have a golden source of truth!

Also keep in mind cost will be higher as all data will be piped through the API, which is a webserver resource needed. This hardly scales well if not designed right (think about web server load balancing and resume downloads).

Comment: I don't trust those metrics from azure. I was trying to set it up, basically monitoring only egress and when I've downloaded 4 files only one log about one file appeared. Therefore I'd like to create some proxy where I'll be able to download files from azure and monitor the downloaded size. I know it will be hard but at least I have the solution in my hands and as we are running in kubernetes cluster I think loadbalancing won't be issue...maybe just the resume download is something what I'm not able to create with my own solution.

Comment: How long did you wait until you queried the logs? It takes time, It's not a realtime DB. Also put in a ticket to Azure. They'll help on such questions as technology is closed source (even though some OpenSource is involved here and there) and they are the only ones having the complete overview. I'd highly doubt the 'loose' file downloads nor size transferred, especially as that's the most important metrics of all. Other customers would have complained already .

Comment: Load balancing is related to a session when downloading data. Especially when you have  a multipart download you need sticky session or some more elegant "magic" behind the scenes to get directed back to the same machine. I wasn't talking about machine count.